# How to set sonar.projectBaseDir in SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I try to analyze one module of a multi module project in Jenkins with [SonarQube Scanner](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sonar) plug-in (version 2.5). Unfortunately, Jenkins picks the wrong module as working directory.

In this particular case, I could change the order of the modules, but in general (more than one analyzed module) it is not working. So I want to fix the problem with the property `sonar.projectBaseDir`, see [Advanced SonarQube Scanner Usages](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages):

> ### Alternate Analysis Directory
>
> If the files to be analyzed are not in the directory where the analysis starts from, use the `sonar.projectBaseDir` property to move analysis to a different directory. E.G. analysis begins from `jenkins/jobs/myjob/workspace` but the files to be analyzed are in `ftpdrop/cobol/project1`.
>
> **sonar-project.properties**
>
> sonar.projectBaseDir=/home/ftpdrop/cobol/project1
>   sonar.sources=src
>   sonar.cobol.copy.directories=/copy

I tried following ways to set the `sonar.projectBaseDir` property to right module (`module2` instead of `module1`):

1. `sonar.projectBaseDir` in `sonar-project.properties` file

   But it doesn't work. The property in `sonar-project.properties` file is ignored. The log shows that the property is overriden with JVM option:

   ```
   /Users/test/jenkinsslave/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_2.8/bin/sonar-scanner -X -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9090 -Dproject.settings=/Users/test/jenkinsslave/workspace/Test/module2/sonar-project.properties -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/Users/test/jenkinsslave/workspace/Test/module1
   ```

   I think that is a bug in  SonarQube Scanner plug-in, because `project.settings` is incompatible with  `sonar.projectBaseDir`, see [Advanced SonarQube Scanner Usages](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages):

   > The property `project.settings` can be used to specify the path to the project configuration file (this option is incompatible with the `project.home` and `sonar.projectBaseDir` properties).
2. `sonar.projectBaseDir` as *JVM Options*

   But it doesn't work. The property is ignored. The log shows that the property is overriden:

   ```
   /Users/test/jenkinsslave/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_2.8/bin/sonar-scanner -X -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9090 -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/Users/test/jenkinsslave/workspace/Test/module1
   ```
3. `sonar.projectBaseDir` as *Additional arguments*

   But it doesn't work. The log shows that the property is configured twice:

   ```
   /Users/test/jenkinsslave/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_2.8/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/Users/test/jenkinsslave/workspace/Test/module2 -X -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9090 -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=/Users/test/jenkinsslave/workspace/Test/module1
   ```

   I think that is a bug in SonarQube Scanner plug-in, because it should not add `sonar.projectBaseDir` option if there is already such option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution, I have to add the property `sonar.projectBaseDir` as *Analysis properties*.

**Configuration:**

[image: Sonar Scanner for Jenkins configuration]

**Log:**

```
/Users/test/jenkinsslave/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner_2.8/bin/sonar-scanner -X -e -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube:9090 -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=./../module2
```

Comment: Why can't the scanner plugin find the `sonar-project.properties` file located at the root of the workspace automatically? It contains all the analysis properties needed.
Is there something we can enter on the "Path to project properties" field?

Comment: @user1653042 Did you try it? I'm not using Jenkins anymore. Maybe the current version supports it.