# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Project home must be an existing directory

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Please help me How to resolve this issue -

Getting Error while Sending Code from Jenkins to SonarQube.

> git rev-list --no-walk 0070e5865725fdacc46d8444385e337eb9e6c4c8 # timeout=10
>   Unpacking https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonarsource/scanner/cli/sonar-scanner-cli/4.2.0.1873/sonar-scanner-cli-4.2.0.1873.zip to /jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/ADOP_Sonar on 00a4ea1e
>   [Generali] $ /jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/ADOP_Sonar/bin/sonar-scanner -X -Dsonar.host.url=https://alm.accenture.com/sonar -Dsonar.language=java "-Dsonar.projectName=Connected Vehicle Platform Sonar" -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.projectKey=adop:CVPIFBNE:cvp -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes -Dsonar.sources=src/main/java -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=C:/Jenkins/workspace/Generali
>   14:30:02.030 INFO: Scanner configuration file: /jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/ADOP_Sonar/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
>   14:30:02.038 INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
>   14:30:02.147 INFO: SonarQube Scanner 4.2.0.1873
>   14:30:02.147 INFO: Java 9 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
>   14:30:02.147 INFO: Linux 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64 amd64
>   14:30:02.147 INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Dsonar.login=04bcf7a2d5c6a5d44d9763fd840e723cbc85bb7e
>   14:30:02.641 DEBUG: keyStore is : 
>   14:30:02.642 DEBUG: keyStore type is : pkcs12
>   14:30:02.642 DEBUG: keyStore provider is : 
>   14:30:02.642 DEBUG: init keystore
>   14:30:02.643 DEBUG: init keymanager of type SunX509
>   14:30:02.897 DEBUG: Create: /root/.sonar/cache
>   14:30:02.899 INFO: User cache: /root/.sonar/cache
>   14:30:02.899 DEBUG: Create: /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp
>   14:30:02.904 DEBUG: Extract sonar-scanner-api-batch in temp...
>   14:30:02.911 DEBUG: Get bootstrap index...
>   14:30:02.911 DEBUG: Download: https://alm.accenture.com/sonar/batch/index
>   14:30:03.208 DEBUG: Get bootstrap completed
>   14:30:03.215 DEBUG: Download https://alm.accenture.com/sonar/batch/file?name=scanner-enterprise-7.9.1-all.jar to /root/.sonar/cache/_tmp/fileCache9893797395313049837.tmp
>   14:30:05.187 DEBUG: Create isolated classloader...
>   14:30:05.215 DEBUG: Start temp cleaning...
>   14:30:05.221 DEBUG: Temp cleaning done
>   14:30:05.222 DEBUG: Execution getVersion
>   14:30:05.237 INFO: SonarQube server 7.9.1
>   14:30:05.238 INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
>   14:30:05.240 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   14:30:05.240 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
>   14:30:05.240 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   14:30:05.241 INFO: Total time: 3.298s
>   14:30:05.291 INFO: Final Memory: 3M/14M
>   14:30:05.291 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   14:30:05.291 **ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Project home must be an existing directory: /C:/Jenkins/workspace/Generali/C:/Jenkins/workspace/Generali
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.Dirs.initProjectDirs(Dirs.java:51)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.Dirs.init(Dirs.java:41)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.initAnalysisProperties(EmbeddedScanner.java:158)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:137)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
>       at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
>   WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeeded?
>   ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
>   Finished: FAILURE**

Comment: ' directory: /C:/Jenkins/workspace/Generali/C:/Jenkins/workspace/Generali'  looks strange.  Why does it start with "/C"?  Why is it duplicated?

Comment: Possibly related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48080865/how-to-set-sonar-projectbasedir-in-sonarqube-scanner-for-jenkins

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue:

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: Project home must be an existing directory: C:\Windows\system32\config\...blah blah blah
```

I initially set my sonar.projectBaseDir by copying and pasting the path from File Explorer.  The issue was Windows uses backslashes for paths.  Once I switched them to forward slashes, the issue was fixed for me.